# Javascript: using a forEach to iterate through an array of diff types

Tags: javascript

```
arr = ["billy", "bobby", {"hank": "true"}]

arr.forEach((name, index) => {
   if (typeof(name) == "object") {
     ??????
   } else {
     console.log(name)
   }
})
```

Given array `arr`, can I iterate through it with a for each to console log each name (or in the case of objects, the key)?  I figured I could throw a conditional in there to catch objects but from there,  i'm not sure how I can log the key out.

Comment: use `Object.keys(someObject)` to get the keys as array from an object

Answer (score 1):

You could take iterate through arrays item, and check if that object, if that is object you can iterate than for each of its properties with the loop "for-in" loop that takes properties and you can then get the value of properties

```
arr = ["billy", "bobby", {"hank": "true"}]

arr.forEach((name, index) => {
   if (typeof(name) == "object") {
    for(var objProp in name){
    console.log(objProp, name[objProp])
}
   } else {
     console.log(name)
   }
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide further explanation. Code-only answers can become invalid if the API changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the first item of [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), if the object contains only one property. For more, you need to iterate the keys.

```js
var array = ["billy", "bobby", { hank: "true" }];

array.forEach((name, index) => {
    if (typeof(name) == "object") {
        console.log(Object.keys(name)[0]);
    } else {
        console.log(name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function to get the names of the keys:

```js
const arr = ["billy", "bobby", {"hank": "true"}]

arr.forEach((name, index) => {
   if (typeof(name) == "object") {
     Object.keys(name).forEach(n => console.log(n)); // log all names in the object
   } else {
     console.log(name)
   }
})
```

If you only want to log those names out, which's value is `"true"`, add a filter to it:

```js
const arr = ["billy", "bobby", {"hank": "true", "connor": "false"}]

arr.forEach((name, index) => {
   if (typeof(name) == "object") {
     Object.keys(name)
       .filter(n => name[n] === "true")
       .forEach(n => console.log(n)); // log all names in the object which's value is "true"
   } else {
     console.log(name)
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get all the keys within the object and then map over it, however to check for the object, you should also check if its not null otherwise it will result in a potential bug

```js
const arr = ["billy", "bobby", {"hank": "true"}, null]

arr.forEach((name, index) => {
   if(!name) {
    return; 
   }
   if (typeof name == "object") {
     Object.keys(name).forEach(n => console.log(n)); // log all names in the object
   } else {
     console.log(name)
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses `typeof` to get the type as well as handles `Arrays` in a sense of getting their first element.

They `trick` to get the keys of the object is using `Object.key`. You can read [more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
arr = ["billy", "bobby", {"hank": "true"}, [1]]

// With array support - print just first element
arr.forEach(name => console.log(typeof name === 'object' ? Array.isArray(name) ? name[0] : Object.keys(name)[0]: name ))
```

Another solution since you are printing in the console would be to utilize `JSON.stringify` and in this way produce a nice string of the arrays/objects:

```js
arr = ["billy", "bobby", {"hank": "true"}, [1]]
arr.forEach(name => console.log(typeof name === 'object' ? Array.isArray(name) ? JSON.stringify(name) : JSON.stringify(name) : name))
```